# Remove a document from Mongo based on the value of a subdocument

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am very new to Mongo but I have SQL experience so I am trying to wrap my head around this concept. I am attempting to remove a whole document based on the result of a subdocument.

The document/row looks close to the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7e04e3809303035bf6437a"),
    "receivedTime" : ISODate("2018-02-09T20:30:27.118Z"),
    "status" : "NORMALIZED",
    "originalHeaders" : {
            "name" : "My Alert Name",
            "description" : null,
            "version" : 0,
            "severity" : 3
    },
    "partOfIncident" : false
}
```

I want to remove all documents that have the name = "My Alert Name". I have been trying something like the following by calling it from a bash script. This is the command after variable substitution has been performed:

```
++ mongo admin -u admin -p password --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("database_name").collection.deleteMany({originalHeaders: {name: "I ALERT EVERYTHING"} })'
```

After calling it, nothing is removed. Any pointers on how to accomplish my end goal would be greatly appreciated. I suppose it is possible to run through a find and save all of the node _id to run for deletion but that sounds terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a nested field you need to use `dot` notation.

```
db.collection_name.deleteMany( { "originalHeaders.name" : "My Alert Name" } )
```

This will delete all documents where `originalHeaders.name` = `"My Alert Name"`